# Chinese characters in Title bar

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a Win32 application, ASCII only. However, when I create the window, the title bar shows chinese characters, instead of the intended text:

```
//registering the window class:
WNDCLASSEXA wc = { };

wc.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = g_classname;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndPrc;
wc.style = 0;
wc.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEXA);
wc.hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                             MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPICO), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
wc.hIconSm = (HICON) LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPICO),
                            IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU);
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;              /* no extra bytes after the window class */
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                   /* structure or the window instance */
wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE); /*(HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_PEN);*/

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    return FAIL;
return OK;

    g_hwndMain = CreateWindow(g_classname, "Hello World", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              g_progsettings.winX, 
                              g_progsettings.winY,
                              g_progsettings.winWidth,
                              g_progsettings.winHeight, 
                              0, 0, NULL, 0);

    if (!g_hwndMain) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't make window", "CreateWindowEx", 
                          MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (g_progsettings.winX == -1 && g_progsettings.winY == -1)
        centerwin(g_hwndMain);

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */

    ShowWindow(g_hwndMain, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(g_hwndMain);
```

Here is the titlebar:

[image]

When I run the program repeatedly, I still get the same titlebar. `UNICODE` is not `#define`d.

Unlike other similar questions, I am not casting a `const char *` into a `LPCWSTR` or vice versa, so that shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

Here is my `WinMain` (a lot of irrelevant details)

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccel;
    BOOL msgRet;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

    if (signal(SIGSEGV, onSegfault) == SIG_ERR) {
        errmsg("Failed to register handler for SIGSEGV", "");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
    if (InitCommonControlsEx(&icex) == FALSE) {
        fmtmsgbox(MB_ICONERROR, "extended common controls err: %s", fmtmsg());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (winregister(hInst) == FAIL)
        errmsg("window class error", "window class");


    memset(&g_progsettings, 0, sizeof (settings));
    if (g_progsettings.readSettings() == FAIL)
        g_progsettings.setDefaults();

    mainwindow(hInst, nCmdShow);
    hAccel = LoadAccelerators(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(IDR_ACCEL));


    onCreat();

    while ((msgRet = GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (msgRet == -1) {
            errmsg("GetMessage -1", fmtmsg());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (!g_fd.isdlgmsg(&msg)) {
            if (!TranslateAcceleratorW(g_hwndMain, hAccel, &msg)) {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We should be able to copy, paste, and run it to get the same result.

Comment: @chris: I posted my WinMain so the viewers can run it.

Comment: Mysterious Chinese characters are almost always the result of passing an Ansi string to a function expecting a Unicode one. I know you say that's not the case here but I would check again if I were you.

Comment: Make sure `DefWindowProc` is the right version as well. FWIW, 敬 is U+656c (translating to "el" when interpreted as ASCII).

Comment: By the way: "UNICODE is not #defined" why not? It's not 1998 any more.

Comment: The defect is found in the "irrelevant" details. A [mcve] would have been great here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are creating an Ansi-based window via `RegisterClassExA()` and `CreateWindowA()`, but you are running a Unicode-based message loop by calling `GetMessageW()` (and `TranslateAcceleratorW()`) instead of `GetMessageA()` (and `TranslateAcceleratorA()`), and then you are using `DispatchMessageA()` to dispatch those messages.  Presumably your `WndProc` is also calling `DefWindowProcA()` instead of `DefWindowProcW()`. So, even though you are creating an Ansi window with an Ansi title, the default window painting is not going to draw the title data correctly when processing Unicode messages as Ansi (or vise versa).  You should not mix Ansi and Unicode APIs together when handling your windows.  If you create an Ansi window, use an Ansi message loop.  If you create a Unicode window (which you should be), use a Unicode message loop.

Comment: Would that be true? I would have expected that if `CreateWindowA` were called the string would be thunked to unicode and passed to `CreateWindowW` anyway.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Many APIs works that way, but `RegisterClassEx()` and `CreateWindow/Ex()` do not operate that way. The API has a distinction between Ansi windows and Unicode windows (otherwise functions like `IsWindowUnicode()` would be useless if everything thunked to Unicode). This is stated in the `IsWindowUnicode()` documentation...

Comment: @JonathanPotter: "*The character set of a window is determined by the use of the RegisterClass function. If the window class was registered with the ANSI version of RegisterClass (RegisterClassA), the character set of the window is ANSI. If the window class was registered with the Unicode version of RegisterClass (RegisterClassW), the character set of the window is Unicode.*"

Comment: Interesting! So once an Ansi window, always an Ansi window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Basically, yes.

Comment: It is okay to use GetMessageW for ANSI Windows (Windows does this internally all the time). The mistake is mixing GetMessageW with TranslateAcceleratorA and DispatchMessageA. This fetches a Unicode message but treats it as ANSI and confusion results.

Comment: In my case, I had to change:
return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
to:
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
and that fixed it.